# the sentence "Does king Gorge go there every day" should have an article?

Tags: definite-article

If I want to ask about a custom of someone and I mentions is name, do I need to add an article?

For example:

> "Does (**the**?) king Gorge go there every day"

Comment: King Gorge or King *George?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Names in English don't get articles (as I think you know) but nouns like "king" do, which is probably the source of your confusion.  But in this case, "king" is his *title*, so [the entire thing, *King George*, functions like a name, so we don't use an article](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/using_english_articles12.html).  For example,

> I saw Lady Edna
>   I gave it to Farmer Tom
>   
> Captain Kelly invited us

Also, [we usually capitalize titles like King when they are used directly together with someone's name](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000049.htm) (just like we capitalize the name itself).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the king's name, you don't need to add "the". If you're not using the king's name, you could say "the king". Also, it should be "go" instead of "goes". When using this construction to ask a question, the verb "do" is conjugated to match the subject ("does" because the subject is third person singular) and the other verb ("go" in this case) is in the infinitive.